# Diagnosing cause of NaN

Tags: java, arrays, nan

I want to sum and average of 2D array by column and if the value of `e[i][j]` more then 0 , count and sum it.  But I don't know the output is `NaN`,
how can I fix this?

```
public class d_2DArray {

    public static void main(String [] args){



      double[][] e=   {{0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0},
                        {0.0,0.6,0.0,0.0},
                        {0.0,0.2,0.5,0.1},
                        {0.0,0.2,0.5,0.4},
                        {0.0,0.2,0.5,0.7},
                        {0.0,0.0,0.0,0.9}};



        double[] avg= new double[4];  
        double[] sum= new double[4];
        int i,j,k=0;
        int[][] x=new int [6][4] ;

            //average of column  


        for(j=1;j<e[1].length;j++){   


            sum[j]=0.0;

             for( i= 1; i < e.length; i++)

            if(x[i][j]==1){
                sum[j] +=e[i][j];
                k++;
        }
        avg[j]= sum[j]/k ; 

          System.out.println("Average j="+avg[j]);  

        }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here value of k remains 0 at the end of the programm so dividing 0 by 0 gives you NaN.

Answer (score 1):

This code almost too many problems for a simple answer.

1. In Java, array indexes start with 0 and not 1, so your for loops would have to be from 0 to the length
2. You never set X to anything, so `if(x[i][j]==1)` is never true
3. Because of #2, k is never incremented, so `sum[j] / k` is always 0 / 0, which is NaN

Comment: i start with 1 because i want to see output from 1 to the end, and how can i set X in to x[i][j]

Comment: If you want to skip the top row and left column, then starting at 1 is what you want.  I'm not sure what you're using X for, so I'm not sure what to tell you to set it to.  Do you mean `e[i][j] > 0` instead of `x[i][j] == 1`, if what you're going for is "this field is not equal to zero"?

Comment: in here i mean if x[i][j]==1 it's mean e[i][j] have value not =0.0 , but now i instead e of x " if(e[i][j]!=0.0){
                sum[j] +=e[i][j];
                k++;" but the output not true, only first j is true

Comment: You probably need to reset K every run

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the indexes of your for loops should start with 0 and not with 1 if you want to read all the array.

In this line

```
if(x[i][j]==1){
        sum[j] +=e[i][j];
        k++;
}
```

you are saying you are going to sum only when x[i][j]==1 but you have not initialized that array with any value. Thus k is never updated so at the end you are dividing by 0 and that is why you are getting NaN

Answer (score 0):

First Problem is

```
   if(x[i][j]==1){
                    sum[j] +=e[i][j];
                    k++;
            }
```

The condition never satisfies. When you initialized array x, its a primitive array and every alement of x was initialized to 0.0, Now the above condition never satisfies so array of sum is never updated. This means every element of sum arrray is also initialized to zero. at the end when u divide 0/0, result si Nan (k is never incremented as condition never satisfies)